# ioctl to partition - disk error?

Tags: partitioning, kernel

I see the following lines flooded in my /var/log/messages file.

```
mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition
```

The following lines were also seen but now I've fixed this issue, could this be related to it?

```
nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
```

Is this due to some hardware fault and if not, how can we locate and possibly solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ioctl messages are harmless. They are due to bugs in the kernel and/or mdadm and they have been fixed in later versions. They have nothing to do with hardware issues and can be safely ignored. (I've seen them on countless systems.)

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=656899 and https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/1/24/136 for more details.